# How can the date() method get the exact time in our timezone?

Tags: javascript

I was using the getHours() method in one of my projects and I thought that I had to shift the hours forward/backward to get the time to my timezone, but surprisingly this isn't the case. I'm curious as to how the date() method gets the exact time in our timezone?

Comment: It just uses the local computer's timezone settings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: This may be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions

Answer (score 1):

Javascript runs in the browser. The browser knows what timezone and the exact date of the computer it is installed on. When you're working with dates in javascript, the browser always uses the local timezone.